# What power and type of in-line bathroom extractor fans should I be looking for?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

We had some mould appear in our bathroom and I suspected that our inline extractor fan was underpowered. As it happens the extractor just stopped working, so I'm in the market for a replacement.

I have a few questions:

- What is better - centrifugal or induct? It looks like the centrifugal ones have best throughput but are they as reliable etc?
- What rate is good? I can't find info on my old induct 23W fan's rate, but I assume it was in the range 80-100 m^3/hr - does that sound about right? Would going up to a 220 m^3/hr be excessive?
- Does power affect anything other than the rate?

A few notes:

- The inlet in the bathroom is in the ceiling
- I don't really want to take out the old ducting & fittings, so if it was a round, 125mm fan that would be great. Also 100mm would work I guess as I could still make the ducting fit.
- Fan needs to have an adjustable timer on it so it stays on after the light is turned off - there is a permanent live circuit available.
- Bathroom is approx 1.6m x 2.5m x 2.2m (i.e. 8.8 m^3) Using some recommendations from another answer, this would mean 70 m^3/hr would be fine... but it's not worked out that way before. Perhaps the timer wasn't on for long enough? Or perhaps I can double the throughput and halve the time?

Comment: How big is your bathroom?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/16618/33) might help you determine what size fan you need.

Comment: Whatever you do, pay close attention to the noise level.  A fan that is too loud will not be used.  Unfortunately, silence is golden. Which means it costs lots of gold.

Comment: @NiallC - have added the info.

Comment: @Tester101 - thanks, have taken that into account

Comment: @ChrisCudmore - it'll be on a timer, so no option about using it or not. No windows in the room either, so it's shower in the pitch black or use the fan :)

Comment: the other thing you need to take into account is how long the duct run is and how many bends are in it. Longer runs/more bends means you need a higher powered fan.  Also make sure its not blocked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went for a mixed flow (which I think is both cetrifugal & radial or something), has about double the throughput that is recommended for the size of room (240 m^3/hr vs 110 m^3/hr). Doesn't have a timer on it, but it seems to be keeping the steam down when we shower anyway.

Here's a link to [the fan I bought](http://www.screwfix.com/p/1/26867) in the end.

Thanks for the pointers.